# Why can't Apache IoTDB return certain number of data in descending order?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

The data in Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0 is updated in real time, and there is no problem with querying in descending order (using "order by time desc" statement). However, I find that after adding "limit 1" after "desc" in query statement, the query result is not the latest data in descending order. Wonder if this is a bug or if I wrote the statement wrong?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please

Comment: Can you please share some minimal example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PR in our github community has already fixed this problem that when using `limit`, the query result came back in reverse order, You can update to the latest Version 1.1.0 of Apache IoTDB and try the statement again.